# PHP notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Url::$id has no effect

Tags: php, yii

I use Yii, and I get this error; What should I understand and do?

Not a duplicate of: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421661/getting-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-has-no-effect-notice) or any other;

error is at: `->bindParam(":url_id", $url->id)`

```
$url = Url::model()->findByAttributes(array('link' => $_url));
        if (empty($url)) {
            $url = new Url();
            $url->website_id = $website->id;
            $url->link = $_url;
            $url->title = '';
            $url->description = '';
            $url->doctype = $_doctype;
            $url->visits = 1;
            $url->created = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',time());
            $url->updated = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',time());
            $url->status = 1;
            $url->save(false);
        } else {
            // update visits
            $url->saveCounters(array('visits' => 1));
            // url existed, let's load products
            if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
                $sql = "select u.id from url as u
                    left join url_follower as u_f
                    on u.id = u_f.url_id and u_f.user_id = :user_id
                    where u.id =:url_id";
                $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)
                        ->bindParam(":url_id", $url->id)
                        ->bindParam(":user_id", Yii::app()->user->id);
                $url_id = $cmd->queryScalar();
```

Comment: I don't use yii, but in general, binding a parameter to a query usually takes in the value argument by reference. Accessing `Yii::app()->user->id` by reference would throw an error saying that making changes to the variable outside of the bind method won't update the copy of the value inside the bind method. If you were to save `Yii::app()->user->id` to a local variable and pass that in, shouldn't be an error.

Comment: with :url_id is the problem

Comment: yea, I just noticed that. Problem then would be that `$url->id` is probably fetched from the Url class using the overload __get method. Meaning the same thing though. __get doesn't return the property by reference and bind expects the property to be reference-able. same idea that updating the property in Url won't update the value in bind.

Comment: interesting thing is that this code is part of a bookmarklet, and on all bookmarklet this code works, on this one, it cracks; this i dont understand

Comment: @JonathanKuhn is correct in that the id is being returned by a magic __get method. No `$id` variable exists, instead the getter is created automatically by the presence of the column in the database table. Changing from `bindParam` to `bindValue` should fix your issue.

Comment: yes, its a value, not a param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, tested:

```
$user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
                $url_id = $url->id;
                $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)
                        ->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id)
                        ->bindParam(":url_id", $url_id);
```