# Modify $this->request->data in model CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

How can I modify $this->request->data from model in CakePHP. I tried it with code in model User :

```
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    unset($this->request->data['User']['birthday']);
}
```

But it return errors :

> Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property
>   User::$request has no effect
>
> Warning (2): Attempt to modify property of non-object

If I use (model User) :

```
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    unset($this->data[$this->alias]['birthday']);
}
```

It's ok, but after validate, when I tried print_r($this->request->data) in controller, I see birthday field that still exists in it.

Anyone can give me a solution for this, is different between $this->data and $this->request->data, thanks !!

Edit : My CakePHP version is 2.6.7 - newest version.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Did you even google the error? There are several examples. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421661/getting-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-has-no-effect-notice

Comment: Don't forget to ping people with an @ before their name when you reply to them (like this: @mark) or else they won't be notified of your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->request->data` cannot be accessed from within the model. This data is only accessible from the controller. When you attempt to save data to a model from the controller (*e.g.* `$this->User->save($this->request->data))`) you are setting the `User` model's `data` attribute. In other words, this is happening:-

```
$this->User->data = $this->request->data;
```

So in your model's callback methods you can access the data being saved using `$this->data` and manipulate it as you have found in your `beforeValidate()`:-

```
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    // Unset 'birthday' from data being saved
    unset($this->data[$this->alias]['birthday']);
    return parent::beforeValidate($options);
}
```

Don't forget when using this callback to call the parent method and ensure that it returns a boolean. If it doesn't return `true` your data will not get saved!

If you manipulate `$this->data` in your model it will not affect `$this->request->data` but you can always access the model's `data` attribute from within the controller to see the changes. For example, in your controller after saving changes:-

```
// Output the User data
debug($this->User->data);
```

If you really want to alter `$this->request->data` then you need to do this from within the controller (presumably before the save), not the model:-

```
unset($this->request->data[$this->alias]['birthday']);
```

Just as a side note be careful of unsetting your data in the model callback's as it will do that everytime you try to save data (unless you disable the callback). So unsetting `birthday`would result in it never getting saved to your database.