# php add value pair to existing array object

Tags: php, arrays, keyvaluepair

I have an array, lets call it $order that look like this

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[model] => Test Model Number 900 
[quantity] => 100 
[retail_per_unit] => 50.0000) 

[1] => stdClass Object ( 
[model] => model 2 
[quantity] => 5 
[retail_per_unit] => 100.0000 )
```

then I foreach loop through $order to do some calculation and get another array, lets call it $total

so my $total array look like this

```
 Array ( 
[0] => 5000
[1] => 500
)
```

Now I want to insert a key value pair back into the array so it becomes

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[model] => Test Model Number 900 
[quantity] => 100 
[retail_per_unit] => 50.0000
[total] => 5000) 

[1] => stdClass Object ( 
[model] => model 2 
[quantity] => 5 
[retail_per_unit] => 100.0000 
[total] => 500)
```

I tried 
$order['total'] = $total;
and I get Indirect modification of overloaded property $order has no effect.

what is the right way to go about doing this

The for loop method seems to be doing what I want, but I still get the indirect error. Here some additional information that might be related to it.

my $order array is actually

```
$template->order
```

it gets the object array like this

```
$template->order = $someClass->someQuery($id);
```

and $template is calling a class

```
$template = new Template(dirname(__DIR__).'/templates/templatepage.php');
```

maybe $template->order changes the syntax somehow?

Comment: Show your actual code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421661/getting-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-has-no-effect-notice for information about that error message. I'm not sure how it relates to the code you're describing, though.

Comment: That error message normally relates to a class that has `__set` and `__get` methods.

Comment: wow thanks for all the answers. still trying them out. will get back to you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put the totals in as you go?

```
foreach ($order as $x) {
    $x->total = $x->quantity * $x->retail_per_unit;
}
```

Comment: the forloop by Ghost, foreach by RiggsFolly and your method all works. Their break down helped me understand what is taking place step by step, but for my specific case your code is fastest.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it all in your existing foreach loop you are using to calculate the new total rather than using 2 arrays and then merging them.

```
foreach ( $orders as &$order) {
    // do calulations to get $total

    $order->total = $total;
}
```

Note the use of the `&` in `&$order` that allows you to access that array occurance while still in the foreach loop and is important, *not a typo*

In fact as the array actually contains objects and objects are passed as reference anyway, the `&` is not required in this case, but still works if it is there. If the outer array held anything else then the `&` would be required so it is probably good practice and aids with self documenting code to leave it in to remind the next developer what is being done.

Comment: Is a reference necessary when `$order` is an object?

Comment: Gosh all of a sudden I am not positive, I had better test this

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ha, actually no it is not required, it works with and without the `&` reference. Didnt know that, must work out why that is

Comment: Oh, sorry - I didn't mean it wouldn't work, but I think it will still work without explicitly using a reference, as objects are automatically passed by reference, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I think you must be absolutely correct, I will amend my answer

Answer (score 2):

Just use the good ol' `for` loop:

```
$count = count($order);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $order[$i]->total = $total[$i];
}
```

Take note each element inside `$order` is an object. So use the `->` arrow notation to set another property.

Comment: Or even a foreach loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats the first thing that pop up of my mind, but needs to have the reference `&`, i'd have to explain that too, so for simplicity sake, just a `for` loop :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly just add the key on foreach to the total index,

Comment: @RiggsFolly just a little edit needed, `foreach($orders as $k => $orders)` -> `$total[$k]`, assuming the OP does indeed need them to be lined up

Comment: No tested it, works like a worky thing, assuming all the calc is done in the foreach and no other array is needed

Answer (score 1):

Your `$order` array holds objects, not arrays. You're trying to access objects, but you're using array notation.  Change:

```
$order['total'] = $total
```

To

```
 $order[0]->total = $total
```

Answer (score -1):

To do this is relatively simple, you must first do this:

```
array_push($order,'5000')
```

Comment: Not even close I am afraid