# PHP Indirect modification of overloaded property - With ARRAYS

Tags: php, arrays, overloading

There will be a lot of questions with this error, I have yet to find the correct solution. Mine is strictly with PHP itself, not a framework as others have posted examples.

I am trying to overload with `__set` and `__get` to dynamically create these properties within the data array, however, when I try to create a property with like in the examples below, I receive this error. But I can create the properties if it was a string or int, so I dont understand why it won't pass the value?

> Indirect modification of overloaded property ::fields has no effect

**Class getter method:**

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data))
    {
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
}
```

**Trying to generate an array field. (this cases the error)**

```
$fieldset->fields[] = [
    'handle'      => 'first_name',
    'name'        => 'First Name',
];
```

**This works just fine, but its not what I asked for, I want fields to be an index array.**

```
$fieldset->fields = [
    'handle'      => 'first_name',
    'name'        => 'First Name',
];
```

If anyone else has a better way if this is impossible, I'd love to know an alternative to the same results. Thanks guys!

Comment: The last example _is_ an associative array. The first example is a multidimensional array. Can you share what result you're looking for?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I would like `$fieldset->fields` to be like `fields[0]`, `fields[1]`, `fields[2]` etc. With their own array properties as well. Just like if you create dynamic arrays, `$fields[] = 'value1'`, `$fields[] = 'value2'`, hope that explains it.

Comment: That's not an associative array, it's an indexed array. You can't do that with the `__set()` function, though. You need to create your own method for pushing new elements to a property that's an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect" notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421661/getting-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-has-no-effect-notice)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Gotcha, Yeah thats what I meant. You're saying its impossible with `__set`? I was building the foundation of this to be based on setting the properties of the object in public scope without having to call a specific function, basically for ease of use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify your `__get` magic method to return a `reference` to the property stored in the array. The notice is saying that you are getting a copy of `$this->data[fields]` by value and appending something to it. You are appending to a copy of the fields variable, not the actual fields stored in the class. Which would have no effect on the variable stored in the class.

You should also either throw an exception when you try to get a key that doesn't exist (similar to the notice undefined variable) or create an index and return the reference to that. This example uses the latter.

Example:

```
public function &__get($name)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->data))
    {
        $this->data[$name] = null;
    }
    return $this->data[$name];
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/sdIWH

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that from other solutions, but I sends me a new error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` Trying to debug that, but maybe I've looked at the code for so long.

Comment: I've modified it a little to create an index if one doesn't exist to prevent notice errors. You could also throw some exception similar to the undefined variable notice that php sends.

Comment: Depending on where you got the error from, that would mean that either `$this->data` or `$this->data['fields']` is not an array, but is an object. Considering you were accessing it like an array I assumed it was. You would either need to define it as an array and not an object, or use it like a class which would mean that the append wouldn't work. You could also implement the array access interface with another class. Arrays and objects are completely different things. An object is an instance of a class. Without seeing how you are defining `$this->data` or fields, we can only guess.

Comment: Ok thanks. `$this->data` is set to be an array in the properties. I have the exact `__set`, `__get` as in your example. which also works on your end, so that looks like the solution to the initial problem. I'll have to dig more and see if the property is being formatted to an object.

Comment: Ok i found it. Did some var_dumping and found that I initial was transforming all of the property values into an object for saving methods.